# Error free solution manual for "Introduction to Algorithms" by Cormen et al. for self study or alternative method to tackle them single handed

Tags: self-learning, resource-request, algorithms, textbook

I am a CS undergraduate student, strictly speaking I am fond of studying theoretical CS subjects, the corresponding books just attract me. Now in theoretical CS we probably have *algorithm design and analysis*.

For the said sub-branch in CS among many other books I follow the classic text *Introduction to Algorithms* by Cormen et. al. The book simply follows a logical mathematical approach for the said sub-branch. Now just reading a text and comprehending is not enough, I feel that learning is not complete unless it is put to test. Nothing can be better than the exercises and the problems at the end of each chapter in the text. I make an attempt to solve each and every exercise and problems but under the background that I am doing self-study, there is no way I could reach out to some-one who could check my approach.

Most of the solution manuals which are available as the first three search results of "CLRS Solution" of google search contains a lot of errors and simply I probably waste time in proving that where they are wrong.( The third search result is even not in English.)

Could anyone help me out by referring to me a standard solution manual without any errors. I am asking for a solution manual just to tally my own approach, whether at all it is correct or how a better approach would be to solving a problem. This would better help me in seasoning myself as how to "think" or how others thought are different from those of mine. Believe me I would not blindly refer to it without putting any effort myself.

Or in case if such solution manual is not available (which is most probably the situation) could anyone please guide me as to how to tackle my problem single handed ,remembering that I am doing self study.

Comment: Let me warn you against solution manuals. If used improperly, they decrease the effectiveness of your study. Reading a solution has _much_ less value than producing it. Having the solutions available can be very tempting to take short cuts.

Comment: Ok @Buffy. Moreover if I use it improperly I shall be the ultimate loser as I won't be able to season my thinking process. I strictly want to verify my approach of solution with those of standard solutions and rectify me if I take a worse approach. (Philosophically though, short cuts lead to long cuts later in the life... Sort of like amortized analysis.) Thanks for the guidance and caution...

Comment: I strongly recommend to present your solutions at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions) exchange.

Comment: Not all solutions in CLRS turn out to be codes. Most are mathematical analysis. Shall it be suitable? The site asks about only codes I hope. I am not sure...